# Como obtener un valor de un ID y colocarlo modificado en otro ID con JQuery

Tags: jquery, script

La imagen es parte de un sitio donde cargo archivos torrent y los    subo a otros sitios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El numero (1) dice el total (en gigas) de los archivos.

El numero (2) nos da la opción de dividir el archivo, en este caso no dividiría porq el valor es dividir en 17 gigas y el archivo cargado es de solo 4,6 gigas, por lo que se enviaría en una pieza, si el archivo cargado fuera de 68 gigas ahí si dividiría en partes de 17.3 gigas
El numero (3) son casillas que puedo o no marcar y en base a eso el numero total en (1) cambia
Cada vez que subo un archivo tengo que ver cuando pesa (1) y elegir una opción en (2) que me sea útil ami

Así se ve el HTML de (1)

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right"><strong>Total selected files size :</strong></td>
<td id="total-selected-files-size">20.2 GiB</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

Así se ve el HTML de (2): (*ya modificado por mi script)

```
    <div class="form-group" id="div-archive-max-size">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="archive-max-size">Max size for archive</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<select id="archive-max-size" name="archive-max-size" class="form-control">
<option value="18285760">17,03 GB</option>
<option value="5386880">5GB</option>
<option value="51485760">47,95 GB</option>
<option value="6382880">5,94 GB</option>
<option value="7472880">6,96 GB</option>
<option value="8692880">8GB</option>
<option value="9885760">9,21 GB</option>
<option value="11985760">11,16 GB</option>
<option value="12985760">12GB</option>
<option value="13985760">13,03 GB</option>
<option value="15185760">14GB</option>
<option value="1619999">15GB</option>
<option value="1719999">16GB</option>
<option value="1939999">18GB</option>
<option value="2049999">19GB</option>
<option value="2210000">20GB</option>
<option value="3245728">3GB</option>
<option value="524288">512 Mo</option>
<option value="512000">500 Mo</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Tengo este Script que modifica el apartado (2)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valores = [[18285760,'17,03 GB'],[5386880,'5GB'],[51485760,'47,95 GB'],[6382880,'5,94 GB'],[7472880,'6,96 GB'],[8692880,'8GB'],[9885760,'9,21 GB'],[11985760,'11,16 GB'],[12985760,'12GB'],[13985760,'13,03 GB'],[15185760,'14GB'],[1619999,'15GB'],[1719999,'16GB'],[1939999,'18GB'],[2049999,'19GB'],[2210000,'20GB'],[3245728,'3GB'],];  $('select[name=archive-max-size] option').each(function(i,item){
    if(typeof(valores[i]) != 'undefined'){
      $(item).val(valores[i][0]).text(valores[i][1]);
    }
  }
  );
});
```

Como hago que mi script vea el valor de (1) y en base a eso coloque otro valor en (2)??

No se, imagino algo como: si el valor total en `id="total-selected-files-size"` es de 60.7 GiB **o mas**, entonces coloque en la primera opción de `id="archive-max-size"` este valor `<option value="10285760">1,03 GB</option>`

*Sería un `script` para usar en ´Tampermonkey´ o similar..*

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Me enredaste totalmente, el título de la pregunta creo que lo entiendo, pero después hablas de los GB y ahí ya me perdí. Que es lo que quieres realmente?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Considera añador un [mre]. Explica el comportamiento actual, el resultado esperado y en qué parte tienes problemas. Tal parece que quieres que te demos un script mágico que resuelva un problema que sólo tú entiendes. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: @mauricio-contreras edité la pregunta a ver si ahora se entiende?

Comment: @yussef será q ahora se entiende?

Comment: Has explicado el contexto de maravilla, pero el final me sigue confundiendo. Quieres tomar el valor de (1), ok! Y según ese valor seleccionar por default una de las opciones del select???? Y si fuese eso, cual es el criterio?

Comment: @yussef tomar el valor de (1) y escribir un nuevo valor en (2)
las opciones por defecto del sitio en (2) no sirven por eso creé el script q las modifica pero no es suficiente necesito algo mas practico algo q vea si es 30gb y solo escriba para q divida en 3 o si es 500gb divida en partes de 20 gigas por ej

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta con esa información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.- Obtener el valor**

```js
console.log( $("#total-selected-files-size").text()); //Con Jquery
console.log( document.getElementById("total-selected-files-size").innerText); //con Javascript
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="total-selected-files-size">20.2 GiB</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**2.- Convertir el valor a Bytes**

Para esto creamos una estructura para almacenar los valores y :

- Separamos el valor en número y unidad (haciendo un split)
- Y lo multiplicamos por un factor, para lo cual crearemos una tabla de factores`

```js
let TotalSelected =  $("#total-selected-files-size").text().split(' ');

let Peso = {
  Valor : Number(TotalSelected[0]),
  Unidad : TotalSelected[1],
  Factores : {
     "GiB" : Math.pow(2,30),
     "MiB" : Math.pow(2,20),
     "KiB" : Math.pow(2,10), //Puedes seguir agregando facotres de conversión según lo necesites
  },
  GetBytes : function(){
    return this.Valor * this.Factores[this.Unidad]
  }
};

console.log(Peso.GetBytes()); //bytes
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="total-selected-files-size">20.2 GiB</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**3.- Establecemos un criterio máximo**

Digamos que el criterio será particionar los archivos en "30 GiB" máximo, o el equivalente a "32212254720" Bytes

```js
const MAX_PARTITION = 32212254720; //establecemos el máximo por partición

let TotalSelected =  $("#total-selected-files-size").text().split(' ');

let Peso = {
  Valor : Number(TotalSelected[0]),
  Unidad : TotalSelected[1],
  Factores : {
     "GiB" : Math.pow(2,30),
     "MiB" : Math.pow(2,20),
     "KiB" : Math.pow(2,10), //Puedes seguir agregando facotres de conversión según lo necesites
  },
  GetBytes : function(){
    return this.Valor * this.Factores[this.Unidad]
  },
  GetPartition : function(){  //devuelve las particiones del archivo en proporción al tamaño máximo
     let particiones = parseInt(this.GetBytes() / MAX_PARTITION);
     let size = this.GetBytes() / (particiones + 1);
     return { 
        Size : size, 
        Cantidad: particiones + 1,
        Valor : this.GetValorConUnidad(size)
     };
  },
  GetValorConUnidad: function(valor){ //devuelve el valor en unidades
    let r=1;
    for(let i in this.Factores){
       r =  valor / this.Factores[i];
       if(r>1){
          return `${r} ${i}`;
       }
    }
    return `${r} ${i}`; 
  }
};



console.log(Peso.GetPartition());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="total-selected-files-size">223.2 GiB</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: me sirvió, muchas gracias